# Maven War Plugin: Copy webResources after resources

Tags: maven, war

I am using the maven-war-plugin to copy the webapp resources and a few external resources to the target directory and then build the war file.

Here is the plugin configuration,

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- Importing React App which is not in the build path -->
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>react/build</directory>
                <targetPath>ui/build</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This configuration works well, but the external resources (webResources) are copied first and then the build path content is copied.

Build steps,

1. Copy external resources (webResources)
2. Copy resources from build path (warSourceDirectory)
3. Build War file.

This is an extract from the maven build logs,

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ ReactProject ---
...
[INFO]  Copying webapp webResources [...\react\build] to [...\target\ReactProject-0.0.1]
[DEBUG] + \ui\build\app.js has been copied.
...
[INFO]  Copying webapp resources [...\ReactProject\src\main\webapp]
[DEBUG] + \ui\html\index.html has been copied.
...
[INFO]  Building war: ...\ReactProject\target\ReactProject-0.0.1.war
```

Due to this behavior if similar content is present in the build path it overwrites the content copied from the react folder. Also, it would be more intuitive if the external content is copied after the build path resources are configured.

Is there a way to configure the webResources to be copied after the main resources?

Complete pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReactProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ReactProject</name>
    <description>React Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- Importing React App which is not in the build path -->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>react/build</directory>
                            <targetPath>ui/build</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First question: Really using a 10 year old plugin versions. (maven-war-plugin version 2.2.?) how does your full pom file look like? Have you defined `<packaging>war</packaging>`?

Comment: @khmarbaise , Did not notice that the plugin is so old, I'll use the latest version instead. I have edited the question and added the pom.xml file.
Yes, I have added `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

Comment: If given `<packaging>war</packaging>` you should not define a binding via executions block.... that's not necessary. because it's already done via the packaging type...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I've removed the execution block.
But still unable to figure out if I can change the execution steps in the war package process.